# Parser XML data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing, html-parsing

I have xml data as below, I want to retrieve all station name, id, and genre. How to do that using javascript?

```
<somelist>
<datatune base="/sbin/somelist.pls" base-m3u="/sbin/tunein-station.m3u" base-xspf="/sbin/tunein-station.xspf"/>
<list name="COOLfahrenheit 93 - (1)" mt="audio/mpeg" id="1392941" br="64" genre="Easy Listening" genre2="Pop" logo="http://i.radionomy.com/document/radios/3/32d2/32d25a06-b423-4d16-9541-7980a2669da3.png" ct="The TOYS - +I2+2'5HA%I'" lc="3220"/>
<list name="COOLfahrenheit 93 - (5)" mt="audio/mpeg" id="1453011" br="64" genre="Easy Listening" genre2="Pop" logo="http://i.radionomy.com/document/radios/f/f9a7/f9a74fd5-f1d4-41c1-9f8a-fcc62470bb31.png" ct="The TOYS - +I2+2'5HA%I'" lc="2348"/>
<list name="COOLfahrenheit 93 - (4)" mt="audio/aacp" id="1460193" br="64" genre="Easy Listening" genre2="Pop" logo="http://i.radionomy.com/document/radios/f/f6d5/f6d5d27f-397e-4b67-8564-8f043b2b5336.png" ct="The TOYS - +I2+2'5HA%I'" lc="1915"/>
</somelist>
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can use the same functions you would use for html, `getElementByID()`, `getElementsByTagName()`, etc. Give it a try and see if it works

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var xmlstring = `<somelist><datatune base="/sbin/somelist.pls" base-m3u="/sbin/tunein-station.m3u" base-xspf="/sbin/tunein-station.xspf"/><list name="COOLfahrenheit 93 - (1)" mt="audio/mpeg" id="1392941" br="64" genre="Easy Listening" genre2="Pop" logo="http://i.radionomy.com/document/radios/3/32d2/32d25a06-b423-4d16-9541-7980a2669da3.png" ct="The TOYS - +I2+2'5HA%I'" lc="3220"/><list name="COOLfahrenheit 93 - (5)" mt="audio/mpeg" id="1453011" br="64" genre="Easy Listening" genre2="Pop" logo="http://i.radionomy.com/document/radios/f/f9a7/f9a74fd5-f1d4-41c1-9f8a-fcc62470bb31.png" ct="The TOYS - +I2+2'5HA%I'" lc="2348"/><list name="COOLfahrenheit 93 - (4)" mt="audio/aacp" id="1460193" br="64" genre="Easy Listening" genre2="Pop" logo="http://i.radionomy.com/document/radios/f/f6d5/f6d5d27f-397e-4b67-8564-8f043b2b5336.png" ct="The TOYS - +I2+2'5HA%I'" lc="1915"/></somelist>`
```

Then based on [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML), you can just:

```
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(xmlstring, "text/xml");
var listHtmlCollection = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("list");
var listArr = Array.prototype.slice.call( listHtmlCollection ); //see: stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array
var stationNames = listArr.map(le => le.getAttribute("name"));
console.log(stationNames);
```

Which should give:

```
Array [ "COOLfahrenheit 93 - (1)", "COOLfahrenheit 93 - (5)", "COOLfahrenheit 93 - (4)" ]
```

You can follow the same method for other attributes (id, gnere, etc).